# Cakephp: how to implement custom pagination?

Tags: cakephp, pagination

As in using pagination for custom SQL query

Answer (score 0):

CakePHP has a rather [detailed documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/view/164/Pagination) on this very issue: [Custom Query Pagination](http://book.cakephp.org/view/249/Custom-Query-Pagination).